# SQL Server: comparing if a date between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this code which is not working. @SomeDate`is of`datetime` datatype. I am only interested in date part, no need time when comparing:

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR = datepart(year,@SomeDate)
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = CAST(@year + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar) AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @ToDate DATE = CAST(@year + '-' + CAST(5 AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar) AS DATETIME)

IF (@SomeDate NOT BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
```

It is failing when assigning @FromDate and @ToDate variables, it says : conversion varchar into datetime is out of the interval

Attempt #1:

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4) = datepart(year,@SomeDate)
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = CAST(@year + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar(2)) AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @ToDate DATE = CAST(@year + '-' + CAST(5 AS varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar(2)) AS DATETIME)

IF (@SomeDate NOT BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
```

but not working

Comment: Can you better define "not working"?

Comment: Well for one thing you are saying FromData not FromDate.  Clean it up if you want help.

Comment: What version of SQL you using?

Comment: Xedni its tagged 2008.

Comment: Very sorry, it is failing when assigning FromDate and ToDate, it says : conversion varchar into datetime is out of the interval

Comment: @Xedni sql server 2008

Comment: @JonH it was a typo mistake . post updated.

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because you're not specifying lengths for any of your varchars. Look at the result of @Year. It's going to be `*` (not specifying the length gets treated as a varchar(1), which SQL distorts in this case to be an asterisk). Specify the length for @year as varchar(4) (and do the same in your cast statements). You should get in the habit of always specifying the length of your data types to avoid these kinds of issues.

e.g.

```
declare @someDate datetime = getdate()

DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4) = datepart(year,@SomeDate)
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = CAST(@year + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar(2)) AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @ToDate DATE = CAST(@year + '-' + CAST(5 AS varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar(2)) AS DATETIME)

IF (@SomeDate NOT BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
select 1
```

Comment: Your script is missing some of the components it needs to be runnable. Desclare `@SomeDate` and assign it, then put something after your `if` clause. Providing an example in my response

Comment: someDate is passed as datetime to my stored procedure

Comment: I got that. But the reason your script is (presumably) failing is because as you've written it in your post, it's not runnable. If you flesh it out, it should run just fine. If it's NOT, please provide the exact error you're still getting.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this a bit

**Example (See the Declare @FromDate and @ToDate)**

```
Declare @SomeDate date = GetDate()

Declare @FromDate date = DateName(YEAR,@SomeDate)+'0101'
Declare @ToDate   date = DateName(YEAR,@SomeDate)+'0501'

Select FromDate = @FromDate
      ,ToDate   = @ToDate
      ,SomeDate = @SomeDate
      ,IsBetween = case when @SomeDate between @FromDate and @ToDate then 'Yes' else 'No' end
```

**Returns**

```
FromDate    ToDate      SomeDate    IsBetween
2017-01-01  2017-05-01  2017-09-12  No
```